# Memory leak running extjs 4.2.1 on IE11

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I found that extjs 4.2.1 would have memory leak running on IE11.

I open the following url using IE11

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid/binding-with-classes.html

When i tried to refresh the url, i expect the memory on IE (observed using task manager or performance monitor) should drop and reload the again.

However, i found that the memory would keep on increasing and never drop even i tried to navigate to other URL.

I have simulate same behavior on multiple machines. I can rule out it is machine problem. Any insight?

Comment: If you leave the page and the memory doesn't drop / change it is more plausible that IE11 is the failing component :) all ongoing processes should be terminated by the browser and memory should be free-ed up by the garbage collection.

Comment: VDP, not unless ExtJS keeps that information available to the session for some reason. This has to be tested against multiple browsers and if this is the case, open a bug report in the Sencha Forum. However I tend to agree that it is an IE bug, mainly because I hate IE

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem in Extjs 4.1.3 with IE 8 9 10 11 too.
It occurs when the Ajax request is not yet responded and the page is unloaded. My application was serious affected. I use jquery to send the ajax to fix it(However, some parts are needed to be rewritten). To solve it totally, we may need Sencha Support to check on it.